# Can I hide part of display by increasing resolution of monitor?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, resolution, amd-radeon

So I am trying to run a fullscreen application and want to hide, say 100px width in the center from the display. Is it possible ? If you see the image , I have (1080x1920p)*2 monitors. The final resolution I want to achieve is (1080+100+1080)*1920p.

[image]

Where 100*1920p not showing up (or showing up in a virtual monitor that is not present)

Is there a workaround I can do ? Or I am looking at the problem statement very differently ?

Comment: This is between two monitors? One Form? Is this for programming? And what does this dead space actually do? Just so you do not split on text?

Comment: @AthomSfere Not exactly , it draws the screen but outside. I want to hide something in the middle of screen.

Comment: Just to explain - I am trying to run a video programatically which is 2260x1920 and want to hide the middle 100x1920 without rerendering the video. I am learning that in Windows XP there was something called "Hide resolution out of display", That should have done the trick but I may need a time machine to get it back.

Comment: So make it transparent?

Comment: @AthomSfere it is a fullscreen application. i don't have control.